# How to pass a react component a redux action as a prop

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I want to create a generic checkbox UI component wrapped in redux connect. 
I'd like to pass the component a redux action as a prop so I can then use this action on the connect dispatch action:

```
const CheckBoxWithState = connect(
  state => ({
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx
  }),
  dispatch => (
    dispatch(this.props.reduxAction)
  ),
)(CheckBox)
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes, but I would pass in the state mapper from outside, so create a function that set `CheckBoxWithState = (statemap, dispatch) => connect( statemap, dispatch)(CheckBox)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of `connect` (`mapDispatchToProps`) gets two parameters: `dispatch` and the `props` of the component. So you could use `props` like this:

```
const CheckBoxWithState = connect(
  state => ({
    xxxxxxxxxxxxx
  }),
  (dispatch, props) => ({
    action: actionPayload =>
      dispatch({ type: props.reduxAction, payload: actionPayload })
  })
)(CheckBox);
```

Then call the action in CheckBox:

```
const CheckBox = (props) => {
   const { action } = props;
   const onChange = (value) => {
      action({ checked: value });
   }
   // ...
}
```